# Why doesn't the 2nd row stretch?

Tags: html, html-table

In the code below, the first row stretches to fill the screen, but the 2nd table stops stretching at ~1000px.  I've set percentages on all the columns.  Why isn't the 2nd table stretching?  Thanks in advance.

```html
<h2>
  Education
</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" width=20% style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc">ABMS Continuing Certification Directory</td>
    <td width=25% style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc"><strong>Provider: </strong>MULTIPLE CME PROVIDERS OF BOARD-APPROVED MOC ACTIVITIES</td>
    <td rowspan="3" width=45% style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc"><strong>Overview: </strong>With its integrated search tool, the ABMS Continuing Certification Directory&#8482; helps diplomates identify relevant, quality continuing medical education (CME) activities that have been approved for MOC by participating
      ABMS Member Boards. MOC activities indexed in the Directory reflect the latest best practices, evidence-based guidelines and educational initiatives designed to support the development of high-functioning physicians. The Directory also offers physicians
      and CME providers access to additional continuing certification information and resources.</td>
    <td width=10% rowspan=3 style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc"><a href="https://www.continuingcertification.org/specialty-boards/">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=25% rowspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc"><strong>Content Area: </strong>ALL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" width=20% style="border-bottom: 1px solid #777777">Assessment Articles</td>
    <td width=25%><strong>Provider: </strong>MULTIPLE PROVIDERS</td>
    <td rowspan="2" width=45% style="border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><strong>Overview: </strong>Articles available to choose from to include on your assessment.</td>
    <td width=10% rowspan=2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><a href="#">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=25% style="border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><strong>Content Area: </strong>ALL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>
  FAQs
</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" width=20% style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #777777">MOC FAQs</td>
    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc"><strong>Provider: </strong>ABMS</td>
    <td rowspan="2" width=45% style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><strong>Overview: </strong>Information about the CertLink Platform and Pilot Programs</td>
    <td width=10% rowspan=2 style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><a href="#">View</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #777777"><strong>Content Area: </strong>ALL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: give your table a width of 100% - your second table doesn't stretch as it doesn't have enough content in it for larger screens

Comment: What "row" are you talking about? The code is quite confusing, with several different `table`s. The first one has cells with `rowspan="3"` in a table with only two rows...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks, I've updated the question to specify that the 2nd table wasn't stretching.